# Remainder when a number is divided by its sum of the digits.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $s(n)$ denote the sum of the digits of $n.$ Then find the maximum remainder when $n$ is divided by $s(n)$ if $n$ is a two digit number.

Comment: Can't you just brute force it? A programm that tests all 100 possibilities can be written very quickly...

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A070635

Answer (score 4):

For two-digit numbers, the largest digit sum is $18$, which only occurs for $n=99$, but $99\bmod18=9$.  This rules out $17$ as a possible answer for the largest remainder.

The digit sum $17$ occurs only for $n=98$ and $n=89$.  But $98\bmod17=13$ and $89\bmod17=4$, which rules out $16$ as a possible answer.

The digit sum $16$ occurs for $97$, $88$, and $79$.  Testing these, we find

$$\begin{align}
97\bmod16&=1\\
88\bmod16&=8\\
79\bmod16&=15
\end{align}$$

and there we have it:  $15$ is the largest possible remainder (and occurs at $n=79$).

Given the erratic nature of the [sequence of remainders](http://oeis.org/A070635), I don't see any easy alternative to this kind of case by case approach if, for example, you ask the same question for three-digit numbers.